# Spring Dependency injection, singleton bean injection

Tags: spring

In Spring Dependency injection, if a prototype bean is injected in a singleton bean and after declaring the applicationcontext i am calling the getbean method for the singleton class object, then how many new instances are created for the prototype bean inside the singleton object?

Comment: What prevents you from testing it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Spring creates new instance of prototype bean every time it needed (for each `@Autowired` in application context). So in your case Spring creates only one instance of prototype (to inject it into a singleton bean).

Comment: This means each time i run the application the getbean method will create a new prototype object.